# FireFox not rendering font correctly

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why FireFox is not rendering the Lucida Sans Unicode font type? It's a default websafe font according to w3schools. Chrome and IE both render it fine.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-width: 950px;
    color: #000;
    font: normal 12px "Lucida Sans Unicode" Geneva, Tahoma;
}
```

Comment: *accord to w3schools* - Do not reference w3schools here unless you want problems. http://w3fools.com

Comment: @JaredFarrish whats a good site to keep up to date on all markup and css changes?

Comment: You're always better off going to the source, such http://www.w3.org/TR/. http://sitepoint.com/ is also a decent reference, and http://www.quirksmode.org/ is also a good one. http://caniuse.com/ is good for HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a comma after the `Lucida` part:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-width: 950px;
    color: #000;
    font: normal 12px "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Tahoma;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GVCy2/

Comment: @roXon - Well, thanks. Actually, I created a jsfiddle and used to Firebug to determine the class wasn't being applied, which made me look to make sure the css was valid, after which I figured out the comma was missing.